# Mac OS Lion in Finder window not able to see iPhone Simulator folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, finder

Hi in my mac machine in terminal i'm able to go for iPhone simulator & can access my apps Documents Directory by 
`cd Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/myAppsID/Documents`

but if i try to open same path in finder window inside Application Support directory there is no iPhone Simulator Directory.

Note: I have tried

```
$ cd ~
$ chflags nohidden Library
```

but of no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, you can go there from:

Finder -> (menu)Go -> Go to Folder, then enter:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/myAppsID/Documents
```

Backslashes are not necessary there, since it isn't a terminal of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

in Finder press `CMD-Shift-G`, then in the popup enter the path you want to go to.

Remember to exclude the backslashes :)

So it becomes: 
`~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`

While you are there you might want to drag and drop the folder to the Favorites section of the finder window. Choose the `iPhone Simulator` folder not the `5.1` folder and the favorite will be named accordingly